Power Automate, convert email attachments to PDF and reattach to email
I need to create a flow to do the following:
For Emails that are received into a group inbox with attachments that are non-PDF... xlsx, docx etc

I need to Convert all the attachments to PDF
Then Re-attached to the same email and forward to another email address with the PDF attachment(s) included.

This then goes to a scanning portal that only accepts PDF.
The current docx>pdf process is done manually, circa 26k emails per month are unpacked and resent out as pdf attachments.
Before I get unhealthily obsessed with this, is this even possible with Power Automate? or is there a better solution to handle this?
Was thinking of a temporary holding folder that does the conversion from docx to PDF, then forward the email and extract it from the holding folder back into the email.

@KJ, there are numerous connectors that can do that, the Adobe suite has more than enough.

I have the Outlook VBA that extracts attachments from an email into a folder.   I can use Power Automate to convert what is in that folder, into PDF.    So now I want to VBA back to the original Email... press forward, goes to the folder with the PDF in, and attaches it.   then sends.

@MarkJohnson, be clear about the product, are we talking PA cloud flows here or desktop? They are vastly different technologies.

There is an alternative solution, it is not inside Power, but a Windows software which can be installed on a Windows server or desktop: Automatic Email Manager from Namtuk, it will do the job.
https://www.automatic-email-manager.com/feature-merge-email-with-attachments-in-pdf
There is a tutorial for sending an email with the attachments received and converted in PDF: https://help.automatic-email-manager.com/support/solutions/articles/67000722228-save-emails-in-pdf-and-forward-the-result
